# The correct way to raise propertychanged in ReactiveUI

Tags: mvvm, reactiveui

Sometimes I need to raise propertychanged for a related property, like this:

```
public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return _isValid; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_isValid)) return;
            _isValid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsValid");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSavable");
        }
    }
```

I could write it like this:

```
public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return _isValid; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_isValid)) return;
            _isValid = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsValid");
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsSavable");
        }
    }
```

Code based on Paul's answer:

```
    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        Validator = new AlwaysTrueValidValidator<ViewModelBase>();
        // logic for IsSavable
        this.WhenAny(x => x.IsValid, x => x.IsDirty, x => x.IsBusy, (valid, dirty, busy) => valid.Value && dirty.Value && busy.Value == false)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsSavable, out _isSavable);
    }

    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isSavable;
    public bool IsSavable
    {
        get { return _isSavable.Value; }
    }

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return _isValid; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isValid, value); }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        // ReSharper disable once ExplicitCallerInfoArgument
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(property);
    }
```

As you can see the code is a lot cleaner it's all get/set and the logic is in one place.

Is there a smarter way to do it? Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ReactiveUI, the desire to do this means that you are Doing It Wrong (or at least, not the RxUI way). IsSaveable is related to IsValid, you should describe that using `WhenAny` and `ToProperty`. Maybe you could write that as:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.IsValid, x => x.IsChanged, (valid, changed) => valid.Value && changed.Value)
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsSavable, out isSavable);
```

Comment: So the properties should all be dumb get/setters and the interaction logic for the properties should be set up in the constructor?

Comment: Yeah, they should use RaiseAndSetIfChanged, and the interaction is set up in the constructor

Comment: From the ReactiveUI docs...Property vs ObservableAsPropertyHelper
You should use a property and RaiseAndSetIfChanged if you are intending to mutate the value

Comment: How to notify several properties upon a single property?